# 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 0: invalid start byte error

Tags: django, python-3.x, weasyprint

I am trying to create a pdf file from an html with the WeasyPrint library, I am following this tutorial:

https://www.bedjango.com/blog/how-generate-pdf-django-weasyprint/

But is giving the error of the description. Could someone help me?

Edit: 
debugging I realized that the error occurs when I apply the output.read ()

```
def termoPDFView(request, id):
    termo = TermoReferenciaPregao.objects.get(id=id)

    html_string = render_to_string('painel/report/termo-referencia-pdf.html', {'termo': termo})
    pdf = HTML(string=html_string).write_pdf()

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf;')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=termo-referencia.pdf'
    response['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = 'utf-8'

    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True) as output:
        output.write(pdf)
        output.flush()
        output = open(output.name, 'r')
        response.write(output.read())

    return response
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to anyone who saw the question and tried to resolve. Got it! The "b" mode was missing.

```
output = open(output.name, 'rb')
```